# How to generate all permutations of a list of maps?

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, maps, permutation

I'm working on an algorithm for a skat-player. Therefore I need a List of Maps `List<Map<Player, CardList>>`. The map has always 3 players (FOREHAND, MIDDLEHAND, REARHAND) and the length of the CardList depends on number of tricks already played (if no trick is played the CardList has a length of 10). The player sitting ont the left side can have one card more than the player sitting on the right side (if the right player played a card in the current trick).

Now I want to get all distributions of unknownCards on the hands of the other players. I started writing a method:

```
public class DistributionSimulator {

    public static List<Map<Player, CardList>> simulateAllCardDistributions(Player playerPosition,
            CardList playerHand, CardList notOpponentCards, CardList knownSkat, int noOfTricks) {

        List<Map<Player, CardList>> distributions = new ArrayList<Map<Player, CardList>>();
        Map<Player, CardList> singleDistribution = new HashMap<Player, CardList>();

        for (Player player : Player.values()) {
            // set empty card list
            singleDistribution.put(player, new CardList());
        }

        // sets the own player cards
        singleDistribution.get(playerPosition).addAll(playerHand);

        // get unknown cards
        CardDeck unknownCards = new CardDeck();
        unknownCards.removeAll(notOpponentCards);

        unknownCards.sort(null);

        CardList leftPlayerCards = singleDistribution.get(playerPosition.getLeftNeighbor());
        CardList rightPlayerCards = singleDistribution.get(playerPosition.getRightNeighbor());

        for (Card c : unknownCards) {
            if (leftPlayerCards.contains(c) || rightPlayerCards.contains(c)) {
                continue;
            }
            leftPlayerCards.add(c);
            if (leftPlayerCards.size() < 10 - noOfTricks) {
                for (Card d : unknownCards) {
                    if (leftPlayerCards.contains(c) || rightPlayerCards.contains(c)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    leftPlayerCards.add(d);
                    // ... and so on and so on, if (leftPlayerCards.size() == 10 - noOfTricks) { rightPlayerCards.addAll(allRemainedCards) }
                    // distributions.add(singleDistribution)
                }
            }
        }


        return distributions;
    }

}
```

This example doesn't work and isn't a good style as well. Actually I tried out something like

```
if (unknownCards.size() == 20) { 
    then set 10 cards to the leftPlayer and 10 to the rightPlayer }; 
if (unknownCards.size() == 19) { ... }.
```

Okay. Can anyone help me getting all permutations? I suggest that the answer is a recursion, but I don't have any idea.

Comment: permutations of *what* ?

Comment: "This example doesn't work" please show expected and current output